How could I accomplish the equivalent of a ROS service in ZeroMQ?
In short: How could I realize something like a "Service" from ROS in ZMQ?

ROS2 is typically based on subscribers and publishers to topics, in the same way that ZeroMQ uses them: messages are published under a path and only clients that are subscribed to (a base of) that path receive it.
But ROS2 also has a concept called services (docs), where a request is pushed to an address and a server-like thing listening to that address will send a reply. A nice GIF:

What is great about this concept, is the service client doesn't need to know who hosts the service. They are matched only by a name.
In ZMQ I am hoping to achieve something similar: I have a bunch of functions (services?) that I want to distribute over a set of sockets (servers). I want those services to connect to a single client and have this client make calls without the client having to know is going to be connected beforehand (e.g. by calling a service by name only).
So the client might make calls to:
/machine/valve
/machine/leds
/global/state

And will receive replies from them. But maybe from a single or 2 or 3 different nodes, depending on what's running.

One option would be to use PUB-SUB and SUB-PUB in ZMQ for these kind of commands. The client would also bind a subscriber to listen to confirmations published for the commands. But some limitations are:i) the publisher won't know if there are no subscribers,ii) there is no way to tell if the published message got dropped,iii) there is no way to prevent multiple nodes listening to the same topic, resulting in double execution of functions.
The other option is REQ-REP, where the client binds a REQ for each feature and nodes connect with REQ. The main downside here is the client already has to split up the functionality beforehand.

The question you asked is a little broad, but I think there are a few ways how you can implement your architecture.

Use XPUB/XSUB with a handcrafted proxy that will dispatch a response to the correct sockets.



Use ROUTER/DEALER with REQ/REP.


In both cases, I recommend reading zguide, at least the first five chapters, since it covers most of the concepts you need to know to implement your requirements.

I'm not sure if an XPUB/XSUB proxy would work, because how would each service send a reply to the client? Also, how would we prevent having duplicate services on the same paths?
I guess something with ROUTER could work.

I started with making a sample based on the load balancer example, but I noticed a problem: the Proxy only has one outgoing queue, i.e. it cannot target a specific worker. All the workers effectively each have a REQ request outstanding the Proxy blindly goes through them one by one for client calls.

EDIT: Oh, that's not true: a ROUTER can send to a specific REQ client with send_multipart([address, b"", data])


I'm not sure if an XPUB/XSUB proxy would work

Well, it would work only if you implement custom routing logic, but doing so would undermine the purpose of the PUB/SUB idea of indirect connections.

Oh, that's not true: a ROUTER can send to a specific REQ

I'm glad you found a solution.
I recommend skimming through the first five chapters of Zguide because you may find a better solution.
Anyway, good luck with your implementation!

It's been a little while but I wanted to share my full demo, based on S.Zobov's answer.
So I have a REQ client, a REQ service and a ROUTER-ROUTER broker. The service registers itself by sending a request to the router, which the router leaves unanswered. When a client makes a request, the right service request is now answered and the service will send a new request. The broker sends the response back to the client.

Note that for the REQ nodes the address in the multipart message is implicit.
There could be any number of clients for any number of services. The limit is a service can handle only a single client at the same time.
This <path> that a client uses could be anything that the broker resolves. The easiest would be to give the service sockets explicit names and use those directly.
Client code:
import zmq
import sys
from time import sleep


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        raise RuntimeError("Pass <url> as CLI argument")

    url = sys.argv[1]

    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    socket.setsockopt(zmq.RCVTIMEO, 1000)  # milliseconds
    socket.setsockopt(zmq.REQ_RELAXED, 1)  # Allow skipping a reply
    socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5555")

    prefix = f"{url}:".encode()

    count = 1

    while True:
        msg = f"question {count}"
        print(f"Sending `{msg}`...")
        socket.send(prefix + msg.encode())

        try:
            reply = socket.recv()
            print("Received:", reply)
        except zmq.Again:
            print("ERROR - Timed out")

        count += 1

        sleep(0.5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Service code:
import zmq
import sys
import signal


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        raise RuntimeError("Pass <url> as CLI argument")

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

    url = sys.argv[1]

    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    socket.identity = url.encode()  # Set socket identification to URL
    socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5556")

    print(f"Registering at broker...")
    socket.send(b"READY")

    while True:
        query = socket.recv()
        address_client, _, payload = query.partition(b":")
        print("Received:", payload)
        answer = f"{url} answer to '{payload.decode()}'"
        print(f"Sending `{answer}`...")
        socket.send(address_client + b":" + answer.encode())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Broker code:
from typing import Set, Dict, Tuple
from time import time
import zmq
import signal


def main():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

    context = zmq.Context()
    socket_frontend = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)  # Listen for clients
    socket_frontend.bind("tcp://*:5555")
    socket_backend = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)  # Listen for services ("workers")
    socket_backend.bind("tcp://*:5556")

    services: Set[bytes] = set()  # List of registered services]
    outstanding_requests: Dict[bytes, float] = {}
    # ^ {service_address: (client_address, time()) - to detect dropped services

    poller = zmq.Poller()
    poller.register(socket_backend, zmq.POLLIN)
    poller.register(socket_frontend, zmq.POLLIN)

    while True:
        sockets = dict(poller.poll(timeout=50))  # Sockets with incoming data

        if socket_backend in sockets:
            request = socket_backend.recv_multipart()
            address_service, _, data = request[:3]

            if address_service in outstanding_requests:
                outstanding_requests.pop(address_service)  # Remove from open list

            if data == b"READY":
                if address_service in services:
                    raise RuntimeError(
                        f"URL `{address_service.decode()}` already registered!"
                    )

                services.add(address_service)
                print("Registered new service:", address_service)
            else:
                address_client, _, payload = data.partition(b":")

                # Forward the service reply to the original client:
                socket_frontend.send_multipart([address_client, b"", payload])

        if socket_frontend in sockets:
            request = socket_frontend.recv_multipart()
            address_client, _, data = request[:3]
            address_service, _, payload = data.partition(b":")

            if address_service not in services:
                print(f"URL `{address_service.decode()}` called by client is not found")
                socket_frontend.send_multipart([address_client, b"", b"NOT-FOUND"])
            else:
                new_data = address_client + b":" + payload

                # Forward request to worker that identifies itself with the URL:
                socket_backend.send_multipart([address_service, b"", new_data])
                if address_service not in outstanding_requests:
                    outstanding_requests[address_service] = time()

        # Detect dropped services:
        for address_service in list(outstanding_requests.keys()):
            last_request = outstanding_requests[address_service]
            if time() - last_request > 0.5:
                # Looks the service is not responsive, de-register it
                services.remove(address_service)
                outstanding_requests.pop(address_service)
                print(f"De-registered service: {address_service}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

